# Dash callbacks that need to make await calls

Tags: asynchronous, flask, python-3.7, plotly-dash

I have a callback in `Flask+dash`

```
server = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')
app =  dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets, server=server)
```

thus:

```
@server.route("/Data/<symbol>")
def Data(symbol):
    ib.qualifyContracts(symbol)
```

This gives a `warning` (in actuality it is an error):

```
RuntimeWarning:

coroutine 'IB.qualifyContractsAsync' was never awaited
```

However, if I put `async` in front of `def` soo I can await the function call (but not even inserting the await yet):

```
@server.route("/Data/<symbol>")
async def Data(symbol):
    ib.qualifyContracts(symbol)
```

I get an `exception`

```
TypeError
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a coroutine.
```

How does one deal with `dash` `callbacks` that need to call other functions that need to be `await`able?

Comment: How about raising a `PreventUpdate` if some logic isn't satisfied?

Comment: Sorry, how does that solve the problem?